# How can i view how differ my database from old versions of it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have different versions of a database. With sql revisions, this database changes on every update. So, i want to follow this changes easily, because my database remarkably big. We'll always be giving some revisions to clients, and actually i have to protect my database model, need to view what actually i did in past on that database. So, is there any way to update my database with some changes, and then compare it with not-updated versions? 
May i have this kind of model?

Comment: If you have the series of changes done to the schema, then you already know the differences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always create a mysqldump using --nodata switch every time there are changes and push it to git repo. Only git can keep track this kind of changes.